# Best way to use multiple canvases in single page

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a dynamic graph with real time array values  which using canvas to plot graph which is working fine, but  I want over 50 unique graphs in single page with 50 different array of values.

What is the best way to achieve this? I have goggled it got to know that using multiple canvas application performance may slow, but my application is for desktops not for mobiles.

```
-- Edit--
```

I did some thing like this to get my requirement.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/atluriajith/v4Rhv/

graphs are plotting properly upto 100, after that the speed of the graphs are getting slow. Is this the right way what i did?

```
-- Edit--
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single canvas that is big enough to hold the graphs.

Then you can use translate and clip to draw the graphs into isolated areas on that canvas (aka. "virtual canvases"). Depending on how you intend to draw the graphs even this may not be necessary.

This only needs a single clear before you redraw the graphs.

In this case you would probably organize it into 5 x 10 cells.

For example (disclaimer: not tested, meant for example):

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    cols = 5,
    rows = 10,
    cellWidth = 200,
    cellHeight = 100;

 canvas.width = cols * cellWidth;
 canvas.height = rows * cellHeight;

 document.body.appendChild(canvas);

 ...

 /// draw a graph:
 var x = cellX * cellWidth,   /// cell indexes to position
     y = cellY * cellHeight;

 ctx.save();
 ctx.rect(x, y, cellWidth, cellHeight);
 ctx.clip();

 /// draw graph here

 ctx.restore();
```

If you can contain the graph within x, y, and cellWidth/cellHeight the clipping is not necessary.

Comment: I have edited question with some workouts. Please check once.

Comment: @atluriajith I would probably use a single centralized loop. As it is now each object (gauge) is having their own internal loop. rAF is a special case in that sense though, but the slow-down is simply a matter of available resources. JavaScript can only do so much. You can use techniques such as reducing the size of the canvas in half and use CSS to scale it to final size. The lower resolution shouldn't matter so much in this case. My 2 cents on that..

Comment: @atluriajith I made an example of this technique here: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/v4Rhv/1/  (I scaled the values very roughly.. but you see the point besides from that, I'll leave adjustment to you if you adopt on it).

Answer (score 0):

Before you continue I would think it worthwhile to verify that you have performance issues.

[*"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)

One fairly straight forward solution is simply to reduce the number of canvasses you're rendering. Make your UI such that you never render more canvasses than you can reasonable support with a given performance. No one needs to see 50 graphs at once, that is simply too much information.